# use jquery replaceWith to replace divs on click of button

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

Hi I am trying to use jquery to replace a div with a new div when i click a button. Currently when I click the button the new div isn't showing it is just blank when I click the button. How can I see the hidden?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="change">Change</button>
  <div id="table1">
<table >
 <tr>
 <td>
 this is table1
 </td>
</tr>
 </table>
</div>


 <div id="table2" style="display: none">
 <table >
  <tr>
  <td>
   this is table2
   </td>
    </tr>
</table>
 <div>


 <script>
  $("#change").click(function () {
   $("#table1").replaceWith( $("#table2") );
 });
  </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

an example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/S8HxM/1/

Comment: Did you check if it is going inside the function , try some alert('OK') there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's empty because of the style you applied to `table2`:

```
 style="display: none"
```

The `table1` gets replaced by a hidden table ;-) so you'd have to add this:

```
$("#table1").replaceWith( $("#table2").show() );
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/qbRcK/2/

Comment: how can I add visibiity to the jquery? in my style I now have display: none and visibility: hidden

Comment: @user1301737 When you have `display: none` you don't need `visibility: hidden`, but you can change by using `.css('visibility', 'visible')`

Comment: hi jack here is a example of my code http://jsfiddle.net/S8HxM/1/ the change button isn't going to the second table when it is clicked

Comment: @user1301737 You have to wrap your jQuery code inside `$(function() { ... });` when your code is not at the end of your body element

Comment: this is what I have and isn't it wrapped inside of the function?$("#change").click(function () {
  
 $("#table2").replaceWith( $("#table1").show());
});

Comment: @user1301737 I don't follow ... I meant to say that you didn't wrap your code in the domready callback.

Comment: I tried wrapping the jquery inside of a a function and the change button still isn't working http://jsfiddle.net/qbRcK/1/

Comment: @user1301737 It's getting late, so I just fixed your fiddle and added it to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the code with $("#table2").html()